# Creating a custom input dialog box in blackberry

Tags: blackberry, dialog

Hi i am new to blackberry and am trying to create a custom input dialog box on menu click event in blackberry 7.0. Everything works fine, the only problem is that am not able to retrieve the string of textbox present in dialog box.

```
public class MyScreen extends MainScreen implements FieldChangeListener
{
String host;
private MenuItem mu;
Dialog dg;
TestDialog td;

public MyScreen()
{    
    final String choices[] = {"Ok","Cancel"};
    final int values[] = {Dialog.OK,Dialog.CANCEL};

    mu=new MenuItem("Configure IP", 1, 1){
        public void run()
        {
            UiApplication.getUiApplication().invokeLater(new Runnable()
            {
                public void run()
                {
                    td=new TestDialog(choices, values);
                    dg=new TestDialog(choices, values);
                    int iResponse = dg.doModal();
                    if(iResponse == 0)
                    {
                        String url=td.getUsernameFromField();
                        if(url.equals(""))
                        {
                            Dialog.alert("Empty");
                        }
                else
                {
                    Dialog.alert("Not Empty");
                }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        System.out.println("Cancel Presses");
                    }   
                }
            });         
        }
    };

    addMenuItem(mu);
    setTitle("Custom Dialog box");
   }
 }



final class TestDialog extends Dialog{

public RichTextField rd;

public TestDialog(String choices[],int values[]){
    super("Enter Host address", choices,values,Dialog.OK,       
 Bitmap.getPredefinedBitmap(Bitmap.INFORMATION), Dialog.GLOBAL_STATUS);

    rd=new RichTextField();
    add(rd);
    rd.setEditable(true);
    XYEdges thickPadding = new XYEdges(10, 10, 10, 10);
    Border roundedBorder = BorderFactory.createRoundedBorder(thickPadding,   
     Border.STYLE_SOLID);
    rd.setBorder(roundedBorder);
 }    

  public String getUsernameFromField(){
    return rd.getText();
  }
 }
```

So running the code, opens a input dialog box after clicking on menu button. Now if i enter anything in the text box and click ok, i get value of String url=="", and I get a dialog box saying empty.
 I just want that textbox value. Please help i am stuck on this...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@AMUL if u dont get perticular button click event than u can also implement alternative solution for that. Implement `PopupScreen` and its looks like `Dialog` .. check the below code you can get easily click event of perticular `button` field.

```
import net.rim.device.api.ui.Field;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.FieldChangeListener;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.UiApplication;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.XYEdges;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.component.ButtonField;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.component.Dialog;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.component.RichTextField;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.container.PopupScreen;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.container.VerticalFieldManager;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.decor.Border;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.decor.BorderFactory;

public class CustomDialog extends PopupScreen implements FieldChangeListener
{   
    public RichTextField rd;
    ButtonField btnOK,btnCancel;

public CustomDialog()
{
    super(new VerticalFieldManager());

    rd=new RichTextField();
    rd.setEditable(true);
    XYEdges thickPadding = new XYEdges(10, 10, 10, 10);
    Border roundedBorder = BorderFactory.createRoundedBorder(thickPadding,Border.STYLE_SOLID);
    rd.setBorder(roundedBorder);

    btnOK = new ButtonField("OK");
    btnOK.setChangeListener(this);

    btnCancel = new ButtonField("Cancel");
    btnCancel.setChangeListener(this);


    add(rd);
    add(btnOK);
    add(btnCancel);
}

public void fieldChanged(Field field, int context)
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if (field == btnOK)
    {
        UiApplication.getUiApplication().invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            public void run() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Dialog.alert(rd.getText());
            }
        });

    }
    else if(field == btnCancel)
    {
        close();
    }
}

public void close() {
    close();
    super.close();
}

} 


Push this screen on your Menu button click event or where ever u want.  hopw it helps !!!
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `navigationClick` in your `TestDialog class` like that. `protected boolean navigationClick(int status, int time) 
    {
            Dialog.alert(rd.getText());
            return true;
    }` it will works ...

Comment: Thanks for an early reply... I implemented that method... but where should i call it. I tried calling it on OK click event but it throws an exception... please give more details...

Comment: place  navigation click method in your TestDialog  class. out of constructor.. it will works .. i havnt getting perticular button click event. . this method works for all button.